# Did Hitoshi (alien-san) gain the ability to feel emotions at the end of the Kashimashi OVA?

Tags: kashimashi

At the end of the OVA, Hitoshi and Namiko are shown together, about to kiss before they vanish.

[image: Hitoshi and Namiko kissing]

Does this mean that Hitoshi was "cured" of his inability to feel emotions?

Does this also mean that the 35 year streak of Namiko is about to end?

NOTE: I am talking strictly about the Anime (OVA) here. The wikia pages (for [Namiko](http://ka-shi-ma-shi.wikia.com/wiki/Namiko_Tsuki) and [Hitoshi](http://ka-shi-ma-shi.wikia.com/wiki/Hitoshi_Sora)) seem to be either incomplete or based on the manga, so don't base your answer off of them.